# How to get name of MATLAB function ports?

Tags: matlab, port, simulink

How can I can get the name of MATLAB function block ports ?

[image: Block]

I have tried this :

```
Port = get_param(SourceBlock, 'PortHandles'); %SourceBlock is the Matlab Function block
Port_Name = get_param(Port.Inport, 'Name');
```

But it returns me an empty char.

Comment: Why did you already [ask and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60391211/how-to-get-lines-source-port-name-matlab-simulink) almost this exact question? You're building up a reputation for this, and/or for asking lots of unanswered questions. Take a step back and consider if you need to spend more time on a problem before asking for others to hand you the answer, or (as I've tried to convey before) if you're trying to use Simulink in a way it isn't designed, and you'd be better taking a different approach entirely.

Comment: @Wolfie When i delete it's mostly because i solve my problem or for example i just re-wrote this question because the problem was different than previously

Comment: That proves my point, if you find yourself asking a lot of questions and quickly answering them yourself, consider trying to answer it yourself before posting! And/or, if it's going to be something widely useful to the community, answer the question yourself instead of deleting it. Otherwise people may waste their time trying to help you (or quickly learn not to which acts against you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i finally found how to do this. To retrieve Matlab Function ports you have to use Stateflow API. I use this code :

```
rt = sfroot; % stateflow root
A = rt.find('-isa','Stateflow.EMChart', 'Path', SourceBlockPath); % Find the MATLAB Function block (without Path property, it display all Matlab Function blocks)
B = A.outputs(1).Name; % Get the name of the 1st outport
```